# Bluetooth audio device connected but not showing up in audio devices

Tags: sound, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

Ubuntu 15.04
Dell XPS-13

I can connect my audio devices via Bluetooth, but I can not use them as they don't show up in sounds settings as an output option (or input option).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

I tried to load the module first but I got a `Failure: Module initialization failed` so you have to unload the module first:

```
pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

and then load it again:

```
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

After that I was able to see the audio device in audio settings.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu :)
I think you should add some detail to your answer, since it won't make much sense without the other answer. If your answer is the correct one it will be boosted to the top, and will thus be out of context.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue here with Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 and 16.04. What helped me was adding read permissions for the gdm user on the pulseaudio bin.

```
sudo setfacl -m u:gdm:r /usr/bin/pulseaudio
```

after that restart pulseaudio (or restart your system)

```
pulseaudio -k
```

your bluetooth device should now be listed in the audio device list.

Comment: I get: setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 3

Comment: That did the trick for me, too! Thank you so much! I was looking for a fix for this issue all over!

Comment: gdm needs to be your user ID (username seems to work too) - I'll edit the answer

Comment: This command made even the internal audio device disappear! How to fix?

Comment: Use `sudo setfacl -m u:1000:r-x /usr/bin/pulseaudio` where 1000 is your user id. Type `id` in a terminal to view your id. Keep in mind to use r and x else all output devices are gone!

Answer (score 2):

Blueman has a [bug](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194006) that will unload `module-bluetooth-discover` if it is loaded during boot so that you will likely need to unpair the audio device and then

```
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Then pair your device and see if it appears in sound settings

Comment: (when I run) ~ $ sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover 
(I get) Failure: Module initialization failed

Comment: When I try to install blueman bluetooth manger I get http://paste.ubuntu.com/10980288/

Comment: I am not sure what is going on

Comment: Similar problems here 

$ sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
$ sudo -i pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

Comment: @select Pulseaudio runs as your user, so you shouldn't use sudo with it - the error messages you cite are totally different, and due to using sudo.

Comment: @cincodenada I think select has more issues than that.  I have used sudo and not used sudo and never seen that error.

Answer (score 0):

After successful connecting of the bluetooth headset, try
`sudo -i pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`

If that then allows you to select the headset as an output device, you can make the following changes:

```
nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Comment out the following lines:

```
#.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
#load-module module-bluetooth-discover
#.endif
```

Then in:

```
nano /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11
```

Find the following lines and add after them:

```
if [ x”$SESSION_MANAGER” != x ] ; then
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-xsmp “display=$DISPLAY session_manager=$SESSION_MANAGER” > /dev/null
fi

# Add the following lines:
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
# /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect #<-- Uncomment to automatically select headset on connection
```

Comment: what if I get `Connection failure: Connection refused` after first command?