# bose quietcomfort 35 paring ubuntu

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I am trying to get my Bose QC 35 to work with Ubuntu. I have managed to get the headset paired, but the headset doesn't want to connect to the PC for some reason.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: Image here]

When I turn on the headphones nothing happens.
I have also tried going into ControllerMode and changed it from Dual mode to bredr

Comment: Does anything change if you `bluetoothctl` and then enter `connect 08:DF:1F:DA:D2:75`

Answer (score 1):

Your headphones are paired and connected, but not recognised as an audio device. If you click on `Sound Settings` on the bottom right you will see a list of devices, but the headphones will not be listed.
I had the same problem and found a solution in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/617603/657036) , but running the suggested commands without `sudo`. So just do this:

```
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Your headphones should than show up under the listed audio devices. If it doesn't work you can try the stuff in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/833323), but since it is already paired, you probably won't need to.