# How to connect Bluetooth headphones to Laptop?

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I want to connect my [August headphones](http://www.augustint.com/download/manuals/EP650_EN.pdf) to my laptop in Ubuntu 16.04. Yet I seem unable to add it via the bleutooth gui:

[image: Bluetooth settings]

I see the TA headphones yet clicking on the entry does nothing and there is no feedback. The Devices indicator is looping forever.

---

I then try to add it [via terminal as described in that answer using bluez-tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101422/12471), yet `bt-audio` is depricated for me.

---

I then tried `bluetoothctl`:

```
 $ bluetoothctl
 [NEW] Device 04:52:C7:0D:C5:69 TA Headphones
 [bluetooth]# connect 04:52:C7:0D:C5:69
```

Yet unfortunately it outputs:

```
Attempting to connect to 04:52:C7:0D:C5:69
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

---

I am also trying to follow [similar question like this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617527/bluetooth-audio-device-connected-but-not-showing-up-in-audio-devices/707962). The are suggesting to run:

```
sudo pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover
sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Yet those commands yield in:

```
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

---

Failing on all of these approaches: How to add Bluetooth headphones either by gui or terminal?

Answer (score 6):

First install all updates

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Reboot

If you have already paired the device, I would do in terminal

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae/raw/d698974910bbb7d016ec0ad08c1bf41b4b524364/a2dp.py
alias headphones="a2dp.py 04:52:C7:0D:C5:69"
```

Then whenever you want to use the headphones in A2DP audio, in terminal enter

```
headphones
```

There is a bug in either Bluez or Pulseaudio that makes it difficult to switch audio profiles from HSP/HFP to A2DP without switching the audio profile to off, then disconnect, reconnect and then switch to A2DP.  The a2dp.py script automates this process

Comment: I think the problem is solved in recent version. Just interesting how my script is helping people to automate the Bluetooth headphone connections. +1

Comment: I noticed some updates today for pulseaudio and was going to see if it fixed this mess, thanks @pylover

Answer (score 3):

1. You may be trying to connect to the wrong headphones. Make sure yours are set into *pairing mode*. For the August EP 650, this is done by pressing the volume buttons `+` and `-` for three seconds.
2. If you now enter `bluetoothctl`, you should see a new device:

   ```
   [NEW] Device 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5 EP650
   ```
3. Pair with the device:

   ```
   [bluetooth]# pair 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5
   Attempting to pair with 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5
   [CHG] Device 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5 Connected: yes
   [CHG] Device 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
   [CHG] Device 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
   [CHG] Device 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
   [CHG] Device 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
   [CHG] Device 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
   [CHG] Device 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
   [CHG] Device 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5 Paired: yes
   Pairing successful
   ```

   Your device may have a pairing key.
4. Connect the device

   ```
   [bluetooth]# connect 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5
   Attempting to connect to 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5
   [CHG] Device 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5 Connected: yes
   Connection successful
   ```
5. Check sound options to see if you are using the correct output device. If your experience a garbled audio mess, make sure you have Hihg Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) enabled.

[image: Sound settings to enable output device and playback profile a2dp]

Answer (score 2):

To enable a Bluetooth audio device it needs to be paired with your comuter first. To do so you enter the headset into pairing mode:

> Turn the device on then press and hold the **-** and **+** buttons
>   for 3 seconds to enter pairing mode. In pairing mode, the LED
>   flashes red and blue.

After that you can proceed with the discovery and pairing of a new device:

- [How do I connect to my Bluetooth headset?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259354/how-do-i-connect-to-my-bluetooth-headset)

In case a device was paired in the past but does not work as expected we may have to remove it first, then re-pair it.